# Why Entity Framework Analyzer couldn't be found

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm using VS2022 to use .NET6 and I am receiving some errors about analyzers not being able to be created in a NUnit3 test project.

> Error CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InternalUsageDiagnosticAnalyzer cannot be created from .nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers\7.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

> Error CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.UninitializedDbSetDiagnosticSuppressor cannot be created from .nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers\7.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to the discussion on [issue #61333 (Version Microsoft.CodeAnalysis 4.2.0 doesn't work)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/61333) on the Roslyn repository it's a matter of .NET SDK version.

So updating to a newer version of your SDK may fix your issue.

Comment: To confirm this answer: I updated my installed .NET SDK version from 6.0.202 (x64) to .NET SDK 6.0.414 (x64). All of the according warnings have disappeared after rebuilding after restarting the IDE (Rider).